# When set SESSION_ENGINE to memcached, Django website halts

Tags: python, django, memcached, session

I have set up memcached in Django using Pylibmc binding:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': ['10.241.1.1:11211',
                    '10.241.1.2:11211',]
    }
}
```

I tested on server with django shell, and the memcached pool workse for getting and setting values in memcached. But when I try to set

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db"   OR
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

my website can still be accessed, but halts when user pressed login button. So I guess this must be the problem with session backend. My website works fine by using database as session backend. I cannot find any related error in apache or website error log, and /var/log/memcached.log is empty.

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bug of Pylibmc, although the reason of the bug is still unknown.
The weired thing is that when I tried the same code in management/commands/, it works just fine. But I can't even cache.set(key, value) in views, which will cause the page to halt.

So I switched back to python-memcached, and it works.